# MYSQL Array-like SELECT Statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

Hope everything is good.

I really need help with a database query / select statement that would give me the right "design" on my PHP array after I use mysqli_fetch_all on the resultset/query.

I have these two tables...

**Products-table:**

```
ID               Manufacturer               Product_Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                 Nike                      Air Max Talldress  
2                 Adidas                    High Voltage
```

**InStock-table:**

```
ID            Product_ID            Color            Size            Quantity

1              1                    Black            Medium          61
2              1                    Black            Large           26
3              1                    Purple           Small           37
4              1                    Red              XSmall          88
5              2                    Green            Medium          74
```

This is how I want my array to look like after I have sent a query and used mysqli_fetch_all (I dont know if its possible with MYSQL, maybe in another Database Management System?):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Product_ID] => 1
            [Manufacturer] => Nike
            [Product_Name] => Air Max Talldress
            [Options] => Array
                (
                    [Black] => Medium, Large
                    [Purple] => Small
                    [Red] => XSmall
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Product_ID] => 2
            [Manufacturer] => Adidas
            [Product_Name] => High Voltage
            [Options] => Array
                (
                    [Green] => Medium
                )

        )

)
```

**The following could also work if it's possible:**

A SELECT-statement that gives me ALL colors for a specific Product_ID AND the sizes available for those colors. I also need this in the **same** row / record (Somehow I can identify which sizes belong to the right color)

It would have been easier if I didn't want everything in the same row, of course, but someone might have a clever solution or creative idea of how to structure it within a single row/record.

//
Neo

Comment: You may find GROUP_CONCAT helpful, although you will need to split the results (PHP explode should do that bit for you).

Comment: Hey. I have tried it. GROUP_CONCAT would return multiple records/rows (one for every color, and sizes grouped by the colors). I Need EVERYTHING within one single record/row in some creative way.

Comment: @CrazyNeo Can you edit your question to show the SQL you have tried, please, specifically the GROUP_CONCAT, and I will then see what I can do to help.

Comment: @MandyShaw, Please read my comment again(edited)

Comment: @CrazyNeo Why can't you group / join the data in such a way as to get a single row, with the sub-array stuff concatenated with GROUP_CONCAT ready for php to split?  Please show the SQL that didn't work & we can try to make it do what you want.

Comment: @MandyShaw Not in a way that would return a result that looks like the php-array I showed in my post. If you have a solution you think fulfills my need, feel free to share. Maybe you know something that I dont know :)

Comment: @CrazyNeo I didn't need it to produce output looking like the php array, I just needed the SQL statement you used in the attempt that got you the nearest (the php would have been useful as well, but was not essential). However as others have now answered I will duck out at this point (have my accounts to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

```
select p.id, p.Manufacturer, p.Product_name, group_concat(`Color` separator ';') as `Color`
from
(
  select pid, concat(`Color`, '-',
  group_concat(`Size` separator ',')) as `Color`
  from stock
  group by pid, `Color`
) s, Products p
where p.Id = s.PId
group by p.id;
```

Comment: Hello @Sydel thanks for your post. Your suggestion returns all colors for a specific ID in one column and all sizes added together FOR ALL those colors in another column, that way I can't identify which sizes belongs to the right color.

Comment: Check if this could help you:                
select p.Id, p.Manufacturer, p.Product_name, GROUP_CONCAT(
  DISTINCT CONCAT(s.color,'-',s.size)
  ORDER BY s.color
  SEPARATOR ';'
)
from Products p, Stock s
where p.Id = s.Product_Id 
group by p.Id;

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, you're almost there. Can you make it work like this instead:


Black-Medium, Small, Large; (color-allsizes;color-allsizes)
instead of Black-Medium; Black-Small; Black-Large

Then I can accept your solution

Answer (score 0):

I received a proposal for my question outside this forum. That I should look at databases like Redis (Key / Value). Perhaps it would suit me better than MYSQL considering what I want.

Any thoughts?